# Translate Mark under Japanese satsuma vase

Tags: handwriting

May I know the meaning of this mark which is found under a vase.
[image]

Comment: Mackygoo,  Noted on the family crest and territory.  Is there a specific  name in romaji of the territory? Or detail of what year this was made?

Comment: 薩摩 is satsuma in romaji.

Comment: How was this ever allowed to be answered?

Answer (score 3):

The mark which has a plus sign in a circle is a family crest of clan of Shimazu. About a family crest, it is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mon_(emblem)), and about the clan of Shimazu it is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimazu_clan).

薩摩｛さつま｝ was located in the southernmost part of Japan as a territory dominated by clan of Shimazu in feudal age of Japan.